# S3 Ninja + AWS Java SDK Does Not Connect

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**The Issue**

I want to use S3 Ninja to emulate S3 in my own network for testing and demo purposes. I am using Java SDK (with Scala).

My storage code works fine if it is connected to the real s3 but the same code does not work.

```
  override def store(bucketName: String, keyName: String, source: File): 
  BlobStoreResult = {
        val iAm = "store"
        val transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard
        .withS3Client(createS3Client())
        .build
        val fileName = source.toPath.getFileName.toString
        try {
        val transfer = transferManager.upload(bucketName, keyName, source)
```

This results in error message logged like this:

```
c.a.request - Sending Request: PUT http://test-bucket.localhost:9444 /png-test.png 
Headers: (amz-sdk-invocation-id: bb866d5c-2ac7-4b30-579b-01df10b96e81, Content-Length: 
924, Content-MD5: Trqia4kjznKAi0p/v3JesA==, Content-Type: image/png, User-Agent: aws-
sdk-java/1.12.53 Windows_10/10.0 Eclipse_OpenJ9_VM/openj9-0.27.0 java/11.0.12 
scala/2.13.6 groovy/2.5.14 vendor/International_Business_Machines_Corporation 
cfg/retry-mode/legacy com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager/1.12.53, ) 

c.a.a.AWS4Signer - AWS4 Canonical Request: '"PUT
/png-test.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Root Cause**

The S3 Java SDK defaults to `virtual hosted url` strategy if you altered the end-point.
S3 Ninja requires the `path style access` strategy.

**The Fix**

This can be easily modified by an addition of `.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)` in your client builder's build call chain.

```
  val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(credentialProvider)
    .withEndpointConfiguration(ep)
    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
```